# How can I bypass location-dependent redirects on a website I'd like to view as a local of different region than the one I'm in?

Tags: website, redirection, url, geolocation

I live in California, and I'm trying to get to [New York's AAA site](http://www.ny.aaa.com) so I can manage membership for my family, who's in New York. Instead, I get redirected to [California's AAA](http://www.calif.aaa.com/), and the *AAA Locations* and *Not your club?* are limited to locations within California.

Presumably my location is being detected via IP address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it is the website's implementation to determine your area by your IP, all you could do is to get a local proxy server to "fake" the website.  Modern website designs, however, allow you to pick a localized version.

Good news is, for AAA site you can use [this link](http://www.aaa.com/stop) and go to corresponding localized site with your zip code.